# why is the sort function of algorithm not working here and what will be the solution of this?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

```
     struct Job{
          int id;
          int dead;
          int profit;
     };

    class Solution 
    {
        public:
          bool myfunc(Job i,Job j){
            return i.profit > j.profit;
            }
    
      vector<int> JobScheduling(Job arr2[], int n) 
       { 
        vector<int> answer;
        Job arr[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)arr[i]=arr2[i];
        int slot[INT_MAX];
        for(int i=0;i<INT_MAX;i++)slot[i]=false;
        sort(arr,arr+n,myfunc);
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int k=arr[i].dead;
            for(int t=k-1;t>=0;t++){
                if(slot[t]==false){
                    slot[t]=true;
                    answer.push_back(arr[i].id);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return answer;
     } 
};
```

**error shown:**

> Solution::JobScheduling(Job*, int):
> prog.cpp:41:30: error: invalid use of non-static member
> sort(arr,arr+n,myfunc);

Comment: Looks like `myFunc` was not declared as a `static` class function.  That'll cause problems.

Comment: Job Arr[n] isn't standard C++, make that std::vector<Job> arr(n); you can also sort with a lambda, std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.begin() + n, [](const Job& lhs, const Job& rhs){ return lhs.profit > rhs.profit; }. which also prevents the issue iwht myfunc not being static